# Could this yield a formula for the Partition numbers?

Tags: limits, number-theory, power-series, integer-partitions

**Background:** Lately, I have fallen down the rabbit hole of [partition numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). Specifically the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)), $p(n)$. It's well known that no closed-form expression (with only finitely many elementary operations within a single equation) for the partition function is known. There are, however, a few explicit, but not "closed-form", expressions, such as [Rademacher's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas). This has got me curious, so I've been playing around with the idea, and have come across a method that I haven't seen documented anywhere so far.

---

**Recursive formulae:** The first observation is noting Euler's pentagonal number formula
$$p(n)=p(n-1)+p(n-2)-p(n-5)-p(n-7)+\cdots.$$
If we only consider the first two terms, then we get the Fibonacci sequence
$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},$$
which [*does* have a closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)). Similarly, any recursive formula of the form
$$f(n)=a_1f(n-i_1)+\cdots+a_mf(n-i_m)$$
can explicitly be solved similarly for as
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{r_k^{n + d - 1}}{\prod_{j=0,j\neq k}^m(r_k-r_k)},$$
where $r_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ root of the polynomial
$$x^d-\sum_{k=1}^m a_k x^{d-i_k},$$
and $d=\max(i_1,\cdots,i_m)$.

---

**Applying this to the partition function:** What this means is that (assuming it exists) we can do this for limiting terms of Euler's formula for the partition numbers. Namely, construct the polynomial
$$Q_N(x)=x^{\mathcal{P}(N)}\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^N(-1)^k\left(x^{-\mathcal{P}(-k)}+x^{-\mathcal{P}(k)}\right)\right),$$
where $\mathcal{P}(k)=\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}$ is the generalized pentagonal number function. Then, the partition function is given by
$$p(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\mathcal{P}(N)}\frac{r_k^{n + \mathcal{P}(N) - 1}}{\prod_{j=1, j\neq k}^{\mathcal{P}(N)}(r_k-r_j)},$$
such that $r_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ root of $Q_N(x)$. Numerically, solving for the roots of $Q_N(x)$ is quite doable, and I have done so and verified that this does indeed (at least computationally) converge to $p(n)$! In fact, for any given $N$, we seem to have $\{p(n)\}$ correct for $0\leq n\leq \mathcal{P}(N)$, where $\{\cdot\}$ is the rounding function.

---

**Power series:** However, we can go further with this method, as this is not so difficult to convert into a power series for $p(n)$. Letting $\gamma_k = \prod_{j=1, j\neq k}^{\mathcal{P}(N)}\frac{r_k^{\mathcal{P}(N) - 1}}{(r_k-r_j)},$ since $p(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\mathcal{P}(N)}\gamma_k r_k^n,$
$$
\begin{align*}
    \gamma_k r_k^n &= \gamma_k e^{n\ln r_k} = \gamma_k \sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(n \ln r_k)^j}{j!},\\
    \implies p(n) &=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\mathcal{P}(N)} \gamma_k \sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(n \ln r_k)^j}{j!},\\
    &= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{n^j}{j!}\sum_{k=1}^{\mathcal{P}(N)} \gamma_k (\ln r_k)^j,\\
    \implies c_j &= \frac{1}{j!}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\mathcal{P}(N)} \gamma_k (\ln r_k)^j,
\end{align*}
$$
where $c_j$ is the $j^\text{th}$ coefficient in the power series for $p(n)$ centered at $n=0$. I.e;
$$p(n)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j n^j.$$
This method too, seems to numerically converge.

---

**Euler function:** One final observation (one which my question is centered around), is the [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem)
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-x^k)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\left(x^{\mathcal{P}(-k)}+x^{\mathcal{P}(k)}\right),$$
which bares a striking resemblence to the formula for $Q_N(x)$ I gave above. I'm a little unsure of how the limits work here, but I think that we can use the Euler function to find
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{Q_N(x)}{x^{\mathcal{P}(N)}}=2-\phi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
So my questions are,

> Is the above limit correct? If so, what can be known about the roots of $2-\phi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, and can this be used to find an explicit formula for the partition function?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated (and sorry for the long read!).

Comment: Also, If you have an idea for a better title, please let me know!

Comment: "It's well known that no closed-form expression for the partition function is known." - well, there is Rademacher's formula, e.g., [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjtgOPJ1Nr7AhWQC-wKHTqbD1wQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.berkeley.edu%2F~btw%2Frademacher2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw176r7maYt0rLADNPva4Q1V): $$p(n)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}(n)\sqrt{k}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\frac{sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\left(x-\frac{1}{24}\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{24}}}\right]_{x=n}$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am aware of this, although Wikipedia seems to disagree on the basis that it doesn't count as "closed form", whatever definition its invoking. I think by closed-form in this context, we mean with only finitely-many elementary operations.

Comment: Is your $Q_N$ related to the $Q_k(n)$ appearing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911496/computing-ramanujan-asymptotic-formula-from-rademachers-formula-for-the-partiti) in reuns answer?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Unfortunately I don't think so, as it appears to be a coincidence of notation. I haven't (knowingly) used any of the methods as used in Rademacher's formula.

Comment: Refer Theorem 1.1. in J. H. Bruinier and K. Ono, Algebraic formulas for the coefficients of half-integral weight harmonic weak Maass forms, Adv. in Math.,  

Preprint here: https://uva.theopenscholar.com/files/ken-ono/files/134_8.pdf 

It has a closed form formula for $$p(n) = {\frac 1 {24n - 1}} Tr(n)$$

$p(n)$ is expressed as a sum of finite algebraic numbers.

Comment: The partition recurrence formula with generalized pentagonal numbers is due to Euler, not Ramanujan.

Comment: @BrianHopkins oh that's right! Thank you, I must have misread the Wikipedia article, as Ramanujan was mentioned just below the recurrence relation.